# Constructing a finite field of order 343.

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I just wanted to check my logic on this type of exercise. I know for any prime $p$ and a monic irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$ of degree $n$ that a ring like $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]/(p(x))$ is a field of order $p^{n}$.

So I need an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}[x]$ since $7^{3}=343$. So I chose $p(x)=x^{3}+x+1$ which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, so irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}[x]$. Thus the field that can be constructed is

$$\mathbb{Z}_{7}[x]/(x^{3}+x+1)$$

which has order 343.

Is there anything flawed in this argument or anything that I am missing?

Comment: It's perfectly good, when you prove correctly that $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_7$ (which you don't really do). The implication that works is the converse: if a monic polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, for a prime $p$, then $f$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @egreg - Ah, I see my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: As others pointed out, you haven't shown that the polynomial is irreducible. I would use $x^3-2$ instead, because the only cubes in $\Bbb{Z}_7$ are $0,\pm1$ (by cyclicity of $\Bbb{Z}_7^*$). Not much difference, but may be calculating plain cubes is a bit cleaner than evaluating $p(x)$ seven times.

Comment: What is a quick way of determining if a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$ in general?

Comment: For a cubic or quadratic polynomial, it suffices to show it has no root in the field;

Comment: In general, proving that a polynomial of degree $n$ from $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ is irreducible is roughly as difficult as proving that an integer slightly larger than $p^n$ is a prime number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost correct, but you cannot be sure that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$ just because it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  For instance, $x^2-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ but it factors as $(x-3)(x+3)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$.  Instead, you can verify your polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$ by just testing that it has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ (since if it were reducible, it would have to have a linear factor).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I suppose I used the converse of:
if a monic polynomial $f(x)\in Z[x]$ is irreducible over $Z_{p}$, for a prime $p$, then $f$ is also irreducible over $Z$. I'll have to watch out for that.